# Web Speech API - Raw Words

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, sound-recognition

Im trying to get the Web speech api to give me the raw letters being spoken.
From the api i have found this:

SpeechRecognitionAlternative:
transcript attribute
The transcript string represents the raw words that the user spoke. For continuous recognition, leading or trailing whitespace MUST be included where necessary such that concatenation of consecutive SpeechRecognitionResults produces a proper transcript of the session.

Although i am not sure how to use it.

What i need is to detect if the user is making a particular sound.
The same sound you make when the doctor checks your throat - say "AHHHHHHHHH"

The problem with the web speech recognition is that it doesn't see that sound as a valid word as it really isn't. so i need to somehow get the raw letters being picked up while the user makes the sound.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html  which is the web speech api (all code will be written in javascript)

Comment: Have you tried the speech utterance methods in the API?

Comment: that seems to work the opposite of what i need. from what i can tell utterance is used to make the api speak from text that you provide.

Comment: That is true, I didn't read into it too much I have never worked with the W3C standards API. I would look into Google's speech API or Microsofts Project Oxford API. Both are paid API's but they are much more powerful options.